# Why session_destroy cannot unset the current session value php

Tags: php, session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Sam';
echo $_SESSION['name'];//Sam
session_destroy();
echo $_SESSION['name'];//Sam
```

I know that using `unset()`  or `$_SESSION = array()` can unset $_SESSION value
But I am still wondering why `session_destroy()` cannot unset the $_SESSION value, what exactly did `session_destroy()` do?

When is it appropriate to use `session_destroy()`?

Do I need to call `session_destroy()` after using `unset()`?

Comment: what is the output of session_unset?

Comment: Sorry the question is only about session_destroy and not session_unset I will change the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual entry for `session_destroy` says:

> `session_destroy()` destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.

So, `session_destroy()` will destroy the data where it's actually stored (filesystem/memcached/Redis/whatever, depending on the session handler that has been configured), but the same data will still stay in memory in the `$_SESSION` superglobal, until you explicitly unset it, either with `unset()` or `$_SESSION = []`.

So, yes, you have to call `session_destroy()` after using `unset()`, as the example on the manual page for `session_destroy()` says: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#refsect1-function.session-destroy-examples

And finally, to answer your primary question "Why session_destroy cannot unset the current session value php": because that's not what this function is for. The manual says it all. Just read it carefully and you'll know everything about session cleaning.